# CSS Menu design

Tags: html, css, sass

Just started web dev, and I want to reproduce this navbar style.
Can anyone help me with just how to stylishing navbart list item for one element? I'll try to learn how to to this. Thanks

PS: to be more helpful, if it's possible to do it with sass syntaxe, it will be great. Thanks again xD

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple! Simply add some divs into your nav. And style it accordingly. I didn't include the icons you can easily find them. The rainbow border on the bottom can also be set to stripes, check out this website: https://stripesgenerator.com

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0
}
nav {
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  /* Border bottom */
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;  
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, gray, red, orange, yellow, green, lightblue, darkblue);
  border-image-slice: 20;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10vh 2.4vw;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>Home</div>
  <div>Dex</div>
  <div>Apps</div>
  <div>Trading</div>
  <div>TV</div>
  <div>Play</div>
  <div>News</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm going to check your instructions

Comment: According to your code, I obtain a gradian under the nav divs. There is a way to make static que color under each div in order to apply a Hover color to the div?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

they probably use flexbox to do this.
I recommend the very useful website CSSTRICKS to see what it is ;)
you can see inside the code of the page with a right click then "inspect" to see everything on their html and css.

Comment: Thnaks for explanation, I'll go to the site, to figure out what I can find